# Not able to apply filter to the property of a collection object in odata

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata

I am using the following code in C# Web API OData and trying to do a filter on the `LanguageId`, but I am getting the below given error when applying the filter

**Models**

```
namespace ODataSample
{
    public class Project
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
        public long CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public long UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
        public long StatusId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("StatusId")]
        public virtual ProjectStatus Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProjectStatus
    {
        public ProjectStatus()
        {
            ProjectStatusTexts = new HashSet<ProjectStatusText>();
        }
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long StatusId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ProjectStatusText> ProjectStatusTexts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProjectStatusText
    {
        public ProjectStatusText()
        {
            ProjectStatus = new HashSet<ProjectStatus>();
        }

        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long StatusId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("StatusId")]
        public IEnumerable<ProjectStatus> ProjectStatus { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public long LanguageId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("LanguageId")]
        public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }

    public class Language
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long LanguageId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            this.Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
        }

        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The services for the above model

```
namespace ODataSample.Services
{
    public class ProjectsService
    {
        public IQueryable<Project> GetProjects()
        {
            var ctx = new ProjectsContext();

            return ctx.Projects;
        }
    }
}
```

The `DbContext` with the Seed data and `DbInitializer`

```
namespace ODataSample.Contexts
{
    public class ProjectsContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProjectsContext() : base("ProjectsConnectionString") { Database.SetInitializer(new ProjectDBInitializer()); }
        public ProjectsContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new ProjectDBInitializer());
        }

        public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProjectStatus> ProjectStatuses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProjectStatusText> ProjectStatusTexts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    public class ProjectDBInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ProjectsContext>
    {
        public ProjectDBInitializer()
        {
        }

        protected override void Seed(ProjectsContext context)
        {
            context.Languages.AddRange(new[]
            {
                new Language { Description = "Spanish", IsActive = true, LanguageId = 1, Name = "es" },
                new Language { Description = "English", IsActive = true, LanguageId = 2, Name = "en" }
            });

            context.ProjectStatuses.AddRange(new[]
            {
                new ProjectStatus { StatusId=1, Name="Active", Description="Active", IsActive= true },
                new ProjectStatus { StatusId=2, Name="Closed", Description="Closed", IsActive= true },
                new ProjectStatus { StatusId=3, Name="InProgress", Description="In Progress", IsActive= true }
            });

            context.ProjectStatusTexts.AddRange(new[]
            {
                new ProjectStatusText {Id = 1, LanguageId=1, StatusId = 1,Name = Path.GetRandomFileName(),Description = Path.GetRandomFileName(),IsActive=true },
                new ProjectStatusText {Id = 2, LanguageId=2, StatusId = 1,Name = "Active",Description = "Active",IsActive=true },
                new ProjectStatusText {Id = 3, LanguageId=1, StatusId = 2,Name = Path.GetRandomFileName(),Description = Path.GetRandomFileName(),IsActive=true },
                new ProjectStatusText {Id = 4, LanguageId=2, StatusId = 3,Name = "InProgress",Description = "InProgress",IsActive=true }
            });

            context.Projects.AddRange(new[]
            {
                new Project{ Cost = default(decimal),  Id=1,Name="project 1",StatusId = 1, Description="project 1", CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now,  CreatedBy = 1, UpdatedBy =1},
                new Project{ Cost = default(decimal), Id=2,Name="project 2",StatusId = 1, Description="project 2", CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now,  CreatedBy = 1, UpdatedBy =1},
                new Project{ Cost = default(decimal), Id=3,Name="project 3",StatusId = 1, Description="project 3", CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now, CreatedBy = 1, UpdatedBy =1 }
            });

            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
}
```

The following is the `WebApiConfig` registrations made

```
var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
modelBuilder.EntitySet<Project>("Projects");
modelBuilder.EntitySet<ProjectStatus>("ProjectStatusses");
modelBuilder.EntitySet<ProjectStatusText>("ProjectStatusTexts");
modelBuilder.EntitySet<Language>("Languages");
modelBuilder.EntitySet<User>("Users");
var edmModel = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", edmModel);
```

The Problem:
I am having the `Project` entity for which the statuses are available like new, active, inprogress etc. When I try to do a localization of these values, i find that the approach of having a text class / table will be easy. Hence the creation of the `ProjectStatusTexts` class / table.

When I try to get the projects with the translated values, I am using the following OData Query from the Browser,but it does not filter the records because the where condition generated by the EF for the **any** clause in the URI returns all the records from the `ProjectStatusTexts` table.

I have also tried the following approach given in StackOverflow, but could not be able to fix. Is there something wrong with this model that C# does not understand or is there something wrong with OData Query URI, please help.

**Query URI:**
http://localhost:64046/odata/Projects?$expand=Status/ProjectStatusTexts&$filter=Status/ProjectStatusTexts/any(l:l/Language/LanguageId%20eq%202)

```
var projects = (EdmEntitySet)edmModel.EntityContainers().Single().FindEntitySet("Projects");
var projectStatusTexts = (EdmEntitySet)edmModel.EntityContainers().Single().FindEntitySet("ProjectStatusTexts");
var projectType = (EdmEntityType)edmModel.FindDeclaredType("ODataSample.Project");
var projectStatusTextsType = (EdmEntityType)edmModel.FindDeclaredType("ODataSample.ProjectStatusText");

var partsProperty = new EdmNavigationPropertyInfo();
partsProperty.TargetMultiplicity = EdmMultiplicity.Many;
partsProperty.Target = projectStatusTextsType;
partsProperty.ContainsTarget = false;
partsProperty.OnDelete = EdmOnDeleteAction.Cascade;
partsProperty.Name = "ProjectStatusTexts";

//projects.AddNavigationTarget(projectType.AddUnidirectionalNavigation(partsProperty), projectStatusTexts);

var navigationProperty = projectType.AddUnidirectionalNavigation(partsProperty);
projects.AddNavigationTarget(navigationProperty, projectStatusTexts);

var linkBuilder = edmModel.GetEntitySetLinkBuilder(projects);
linkBuilder.AddNavigationPropertyLinkBuilder(navigationProperty,
    new NavigationLinkBuilder((context, property) =>
        context.GenerateNavigationPropertyLink(property, false), true));

config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", edmModel);
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear about your data model, is it possible to provide some more detail about what these things represent and what you are trying to filter?

Comment: I am trying to filter the projects statusses by a given language. The project has a statusid which is taken from ProjectStatus and this is localized and the localized data is available from ProjectStatusTexts table for each language.When I get a project, I want to show the StatusText by the language of the user. ex: Spanish

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are trying to achieve is to get all of the projects and then to expand to the `ProjectStatusTexts` that have the correct language. If that is the case then the filter is part of the expand not part of the query for the `Projects` themselves so it should be added in brackets after the expand like this:

http://localhost:64046/odata/Projects?$expand=Status/ProjectStatusTexts($filter=Language/LanguageId%20eq%202)

Comment: I am getting the following error `Term 'Status/ProjectStatusTexts($filter=Language/LanguageId eq 2)' is not valid in a $select or $expand expression`

Comment: This URL `http://localhost:64046/odata/Projects?$expand=Status/ProjectStatusTexts($filter=LanguageId%20eq%202)` also gives `Term 'Status/ProjectStatusTexts($filter=LanguageId eq 2)' is not valid in a $select or $expand expression` error

Answer (score 0):

> Building on the answer from [@TomDoesCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47267137/1690217)

In OP's schema, `Project` has a `Status`, and `Status` has many `ProjectStatusText`
In the resultset, we only want to include `ProjectStatusText` records that match a given language id.

To achieve this, we need to expand twice, in the expansion to `ProjectStatusTexts` we also need to apply a filter.

```
http://localhost:64046/odata/Projects?$expand=Status($expand=ProjectStatusTexts($filter=Language/LanguageId eq 2))
```

This query will return all projects, but will only include the `ProjectStatusText` if it's language Id matches 'English' (2)

> Note, to access multiple levels of navigation properties we must use nested `$expand` operators

---

OPs attempt to filter can be translated roughly to:

- filter by *Projects that have any status that has an english text*

If you also wanted to only return projects with an english status, then you could combine the two approaches into the following:

```
http://localhost:64046/odata/Projects?$expand=Status($expand=ProjectStatusTexts($filter=Language/LanguageId eq 2))&$filter=Status/ProjectStatusTexts/any(l:l/Language/LanguageId eq 2)
```

However this type of filter is usually redundant, expecially if all project status records will have an entry for each supported language.